# Switching from Firebase emulator to production, CORS error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header"

Tags: javascript, firebase

For awhile I've been using the Firebase emulator to test my app, but now I'm ready for production. I'm trying to use a bool to toggle the initialization between using the emulator and not, but I'm getting a cors error when I do.

This is my client-side code

```
let use_emulator = false
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"
import 'firebase/compat/functions'
import 'firebase/compat/auth'
import 'firebase/compat/analytics'
import 'firebase/compat/database'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
var admin = firebase

const firebaseConfig = {
//Removed
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
if (use_emulator) {
    firebase.functions().useEmulator("localhost", 5001);
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
}

firebase.analytics(app)
const validateReferral = firebase.functions(app).httpsCallable('validateReferral')
```

Then I call my Firebase function like this:

```
async function checkReferral(manual_code = false) {
    var ref = false
//Removed
    var value = await validateReferral({ ref: ref })
}
```

This function worked fine before, but now I get this error after turning use_emulator off.

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-psyche-9e997.cloudfunctions.net/validateReferral' from origin 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
service.ts:190 POST https://us-central1-psyche-9e997.cloudfunctions.net/validateReferral net::ERR_FAILED
postJSON @ service.ts:190
call @ service.ts:251
async function (async)
call @ service.ts:236
(anonymous) @ service.ts:169
_callee12$ @ script.js:9803
tryCatch @ runtime.js:63
invoke @ runtime.js:294
(anonymous) @ runtime.js:119
asyncGeneratorStep @ script.js:19
_next @ script.js:19
(anonymous) @ script.js:19
(anonymous) @ script.js:19
checkReferral @ script.js:9787
(anonymous) @ script.js:9895
checkKeyUp @ script.js:3107
errors.ts:91 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: internal
```

My server code looks like this (I removed the irrelevant function code).:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
var admin = require('firebase-admin')

const app = admin.initializeApp();

exports.validateReferral = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log("validateReferral data is ", data)
    const referral_code = data.ref
    console.log("validateReferral validating referral code, code is " + referral_code)
    return admin.database().ref().child("referrals").child(referral_code.trim()).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            console.log("referral code is valid");
            return true
        } else {
            console.log("referral code is not valid");
            return false
        }
    })
})
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That function throws a 403 error when I try to call it and because it is throwing a 403 error, it won't respond to CORS handshakes properly. Have you confirmed that your function is deployed in production? If it is deployed but isn't working, either delete and redeploy it (after updating your `firebase-tools` install) or [ensure that `allUsers` is granted the `Cloud Functions Invoker` permission](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_http_function_invocation).

Comment: The functions were deployed already, but deleting them and redeploying worked. Should have thought of that, sorry and thanks for the help.